# integral involving square of exponential integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I'm trying to compute the integral
$$
\int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{e^x}{x}[\mathrm{Ei}(-x)]^2\,dx,
$$
where $\mathrm{Ei}$ is the exponential integral, and $a>0$. The obvious

```
Integrate[Exp[x]/x*(ExpIntegralE[1, x])^2, {x, a, Infinity}]
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably only be able to do this numerically.

The function being integrated is

```
expr = Exp[x]/x*(ExpIntegralE[1, x])^2;

LogPlot[expr, {x, 10^-5, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "expr"}]
```

[image]

Using numeric integration

```
data = Table[{a, NIntegrate[expr, {x, a, Infinity}]}, 
  {a, 10.^Range[-5, 0, .2]}];

ListLogPlot[data,
 Joined -> True,
 PlotRange -> All,
 AxesLabel -> {"a", "Integral"}]
```

[image]